# About the set of density points of given sets, for the Lebesgue measure on the line and on the plane

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Please help me prove the following:

> 1) Let $A \subseteq \{(x,y)|0< x^2+y^2 < 1 \}$ be a lebesgue measurable set such that every point in $\{(x,y)|0< x^2+y^2 < 1 \}$ is a density point of $A$, 
>   then (0,0) is a density point of A as well.
>
> 2) Find a set $A$ such that for every n: 
>   $\frac{m \bigl(\bigl[0,\frac{1}{2^n}\bigl] \cap A \bigl)}{m\bigl(\bigl[0,\frac{1}{2^n}\bigl]\bigl)}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Couldn't prove the 1st question. Any help?
And anyone have an example for the second question?
Thanks!

Comment: $$A=\bigcup_n[3\cdot2^{-n-2},2^{-n}]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, define $B= \{0<x^2+y^2<1\}\setminus A.$ Suppose $m(B)>0.$ Then by Lebesgue's differentiation theorem, a.e. $(x,y) \in B$ is a point of density of $B.$ Let $z_0=(x_0,y_0)$ be one of these. Then it is easy to see

$$ \lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{m(A\cap D(z_0,r))}{m(D(z_0,r))} = 0.$$

Thus $z_0$ is not a point of density of $A,$ contradiction. This shows a.e. point of $\{0<x^2+y^2<1\}$ is in $A.$ The desired conclusion is immediate from this.

Comment: Does every point in the closure of the set $\{0<x^2+y^2<100\}$ is neccessarily a point of density of A? I mean, from that answer can we also conclude that all the points in the boundary of this set are also points of density of A?

Comment: Why change the radius to $100?$

Comment: Sorryu, I meant 1..

Comment: No, the points on the unit circle are not points of density of $A.$ At those points you get $1/2$ for the limit rather than $1.$

Comment: I see, so every small enough disc we take around any point x that's on the unit circle, by symmeytry, exactly half of the disc $B(0,\delta)$ is inside the unit disc, for all, say $0<\delta<1$. So ${m\bigl(B(x,\delta) \cap \partial B(0,1)\bigl)} \over {m\bigl(B(x,\delta)\bigl)}$ $={1 \over 2}$ for all $0<\delta<1$ .Hence, also for the limit $\delta \rightarrow 0^{+}$

Comment: That should be $B(x,\delta)$. And it's not exactly half that disc, it's slightly less, but yes the limit is $1/2.$